# Issue with graphicx and auto-pst-pdf

Tags: graphics, psfrag, auto-pst-pdf

This is the first time I write on this forum so I hope I do everything fine.

I am using TexMaker and I have the latest version of MikTex 2.9.

I am having serious issues with my thesis.
I need to include many images of chemical compounds, so I am using `.eps`
files, generated from an external editor, calling them with the usual command `\includegraphics`.

Since I need to assign a number to the compounds, instead of `epstopdf` package I am using `psfrag`, `auto-pst-pdf` and `chemnum` packages.

It was all going well, but exactly two days ago I started to get this error, once for every image I want to include.

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>   \Ginclude@eps ...@hidestart \fi \pfg@Ginclude@eps
>   {#1}\ifnum \pfg@scount >\z...
>   l.9 \includegraphics[scale=1]{"name"}

Here is my MWE, which gives me the same error.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage[runs=2, crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{"name".eps} 
\end{document}
```

This happens with every image I use (that's why I used a generic "name"),
also with freshly generated ones.

On the contrary, using `epstopdf` package instead of `psfrag` and `auto-pst-pdf` works, but obviously it doesn't help with replacing the tags, that's why I'd like to use `chemnum`.

I reinstalled Miktek, updated packages and reinstalled Texmaker, but still doesn't work. I don't think it is a problem of the path where i saved `.eps` files, because I tried to generate a new document in a different folder editing new images and still i get the error (and it works again using `epstopdf`)

Can it be a problem related to the update of some packages related to graphics? (I noticed an update of graphics-def available from 07/06/2016, but the problem remains with or without it).

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! A simple thought: did you try using `psfragx`?

Comment: Tried right now, not working. Thanks Bernard

Comment: I think this is related to https://github.com/latex3/pdftex-def/issues/1

Comment: Okay, so it is probably related to the newest updates. What can I do in practice to overcome this issue? Thank you David Carlisle

Comment: it didn't seem to work with the previous version of pdftex.def either? although the change that herbert requested was to avoid a very similar error.  I've pinged herbert but in the meantime you should be able to use the  pst-pdf (not auto) usage as in the example at the top of that github issue.

Comment: I tried to remove the latest update from graphics-def package (uninstalling the package from Miktek package manager) in order to restore previous versions but it still doesn't work. Same if I remove auto and I use only pst-pdf package. I appreciate your efforts and thanks for extending my issue to other programmers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I think this should work...

```
\documentclass{report}


\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage[runs=2, crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\Gin@extensions{%
          .png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,%
          .PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,%
          %.eps%
      }%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{zzz.eps} 
\end{document}
```

the timing of the test to add, or not add `.eps` to the list of extensions
seems to be wrong for the auto- version. if you confirm this works for you 
I'll sort out an update ..

Comment: Simply perfect. It works smoothly and it also replaces chemnum tags. My thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Load `pst-pdf` as first package:

```
\usepackage{pst-pdf}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage[runs=2, crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggest, but I get an error message "the file is already in use by another process" and pdflatex goes in a loop. I tried to kill every possible process, and even to restart the pc, but it still gives that error. I will try again, maybe on a fresh document. Thanks Herbert

Comment: I tried it with an up- to- date texlive 2016

Comment: I am sure you made it work on texlive. Unfortunately at the moment on texmaker (I checked and it is up to date) the only working solution is David Carlisle's one. I don't understand if it is a problem of the editor or what. Thank you anyway for the attempt.

Comment: texmaker is an Editor and has nothing to do with your Problem. If my solution doesn't help, then you do not have the up-to-date versin of pdftex.def which already had the fix